# C++ nested lookup maps of different type at run time

Tags: c++, templates, nested, c++14

I have to convert a multi-columns lookup object from Java to C++14 (C++17 or boost are not to consider ie: variant/any).

The lookup data are loaded at run time (from csv or json) and can hold 4 types `std::string`, `int`, `double`, `long long`. A file can contains 2 to N columns. Below a simple example:

```
Country    Dept  Ratio   Final
"FR"        75     1.25    12
"FR"        01     0.25    15
"UK"        24     1.5     7
....
```

The goal is to find the Final value using N-1 parameters (matching each column).

Each column (except Final) contains a parameter "search" that can be =, <, > . The search is always done on equal and if not found and "search" is < or > we use the closest < or > match.

An example query is done this way lookup("FR", 72, 1.28) for example.

In Java this is implemented using nested `TreeMap` which is the equivalent of std::map, but they can be instantiated at run time (because it's java).

So far I have used `std::map` but my implementation is quite heavy since it's done with nested class that dynamic cast a `shared_ptr<void>` etc..

I am trying to figure out a nice "template way" for implementing this (using `std::map` or something else).

Any hints appreciated

EDIT:
We can have 1000's of entries, my idea was to make, for the example of data above, the equivalent of

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<int, std::map<double, int>>>
```

But as the types are known at run time only, the above can't be done.
I tested also this:

```
struct BaseDimension
{
}

template<typename X, typename Y>
struct Dimension: BaseDimension
{
    std::shared_ptr<std::map<X, Y>> _map;
}
```

But I have problem to organize the "Tree" from there, from BaseDimension how to dynamic cast to the Dimension avoiding a switch to all possible type pairs.

Using the same data sample, we would have been

```
Dimension<std::string, BaseDimension>
           Dimension<int ,BaseDimension>
                    Dimension<double, int>
```

I just found an std::variant for C++ 14 (mapbox), I'll check if it makes this easier

Comment: Do you use any library for json? As json object is mostly a variant.

Comment: Json is just one of the source type of file, the lookup object is created at run time reading files (I might have several files this several lookups)

Comment: I meant, if you cannot use `std::variant` or `boost::variant` (or from any other libraries), you might "abuse" of your json library and use json value as variant.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "_but my implementation is quite heavy since it's done with nested class that dynamic cast a shared_ptr<void> etc.._". Could you share your C++ implementation? Sharing the Java implementation might also help provide a comparable solution in C++.